# umbraco razor - check if field exists

Tags: variables, razor, umbraco, undefined

I have the follow code, however I get an error if I have no image (it is a media picker)

```cs
<umbraco:Macro runat="server" language="cshtml">
@{
    dynamic image = new umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicMedia(@Model.whereMap);
    <img class="where-map" src="@image.umbracoFile" width="150" height="250"/>
 }
</umbraco:Macro>
```

I have tried all the obvious stuff for checking a null valaue but no joy.

Thanks

Comment: what's the error, and what are the "obvious stuff" you've tried?

Comment: if(Model.whereMap== null) jsut a basic macro did not load error

Comment: As it's a picker, populated with int, doesn't that mean that @Model.whereMap would not be null, but in fact "0"? Maybe check if "image" is null, or whereMap > 0, or wrap in try...catch.

Answer (score 10):

Check out these razor methods:

- @Model.HasProperty(string propertyAlias)
- @Model.HasValue(string propertyAlias)
- @Model.IsNull(string propertyAlias)

Refer: [Umbraco Razor cheat-sheet](http://our.umbraco.org/FileDownload?id=3103)

Answer (score 4):

In Umbraco 6 MVC you could use

Typed:

```
@{
    if(Model.Content.HasValue("mainImage")){
        var mediaItem = Umbraco.TypedMedia(Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("mainImage")); 
        <img src="@mediaItem.GetPropertyValue("umbracoFile")" alt="@mediaItem.GetPropertyValue("Name")"/>    
    }   
}
```

Dynamic:

```
@{      
    if (CurrentPage.HasValue("mainImage")){                                         
        var dynamicMediaItem = Umbraco.Media(CurrentPage.mainImage);
        <img src="@dynamicMediaItem.umbracoFile" alt="@dynamicMediaItem.Name"/>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
CurrentPage.HasProperty("mainImage")
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with Following code

```
@if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(@Model.whereMap))
{
 <img class="where-map" src="@image.umbracoFile" width="150" height="250"/> 
}
```